# How to deploy folder which is not included while publishing to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

we are following plugin architecture, so we are having other projects which can plugin into the main web application.Right now we are using installshield to deploy our dlls from other projects into the main web application.

Folder structure:
MVC Application

-- bin

--Plugins

```
  -- Plugin1

      -- dlls

  -- Plugin2

       --dlls
```

When I  published my application to Azure App service.The dlls present in the main web application only got copied.How can I move the dlls present in my plugins folder.

Do we need to add any settings in publish profile to include these publish dlls?
Please let me know how can i include the plugins folder

Comment: Are you deploying from Visual Studio? or using any sort of build automation like VSTS?

Comment: Doing from VS2015

Answer (score 0):

If those files exist in project, just make sure you set the build action to Content and they will get deployed. Note that this is standard msdeploy behavior, and not specifically about Azure.

Comment: those files are dynamic.I am looking for deployment to Azure