# Facing issue with application after Deployment to Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

we are following plugin architecture, so we are having other projects which can plugin into the main web application.

Folder structure:

--MVC Application

-- bin

--Plugins

-- Plugin1

```
  -- dlls
```

-- Plugin2

```
   --dlls
```

When I published my  MVC application to Azure App service.The dlls present in the main web application only got copied.How can I move the dlls present in my plugins folder.

When I try to run the application it is not loading the scripts and dlls  present in other plugin folders.

Can some one please let me know how can I solve the issue and these plugins are dynamic.

Based on the post build event, we are copying the dlls and scripts to respective plugin folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy folder which is not included while publishing to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998735/how-to-deploy-folder-which-is-not-included-while-publishing-to-azure)

Comment: Set BuildAction to "content" in items properties.